# How to find that the point is between two points

Tags: actionscript-3

I have been trying to create a curve and i've already created it . but the thing is if i add a point it will be added to the array[last point -1] , but if i add a point between the first and second point the curve takes it as the last point -1 which is my coding anyway,

```
function findpoints()
{
var newPt:Point = new Point(evt.stageX, evt.stageY);
_points[poin] = newPt;
//trace(_points)
poin += 1;
redrawCanvas();
}
```

i just want to know whether i can find a function

Comment: You will have to handle this issue by yourself. There is no ready-made function that will do what you are trying to accomplish, so you have to walk through your array, find out if the new point is supposed to be between two existing, then insert it into the array if yes.

Comment: Yeah i know the concept   all i was asking about is the functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After serious and continuous research i've found the answer for the question , all you need to find is the end points and have it and the points array and then you can able to find whether it is between those specific points using this formulation and able to add it to the array based on the terms ,

```
var pt:Point = new Point(Cmenu.x,Cmenu.y);
        for (var i:int =0; i <= _points.length-1; i++)
        {
            var ss:int = (_points[i] as Point).x;
            var sss:int = (_points[i] as Point).y;
            if(pt.x > ss )
            {
                var change:int = i+1;                                       
            }

        }
        _points.splice(change,0,pt);
```

I got the desired output , posting it here in case someone needs it in future.